# Where does amcl_demo.launch load its plugins from?

Tags: navigation, amcl-demo.launch, plugin, amcl, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=<path_of_my_map>` I get, as part of the output:

```
[ INFO] [1396554684.603955092]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1396554684.956445219]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1396554685.162530181]: Resizing costmap to 480 X 288 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1396554685.262220473]: Received a 480 X 288 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1396554685.288558669]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1396554685.355236864]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan bump
[ INFO] [1396554685.659024142]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1396554686.518542435]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1396554686.738804760]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1396554687.077918589]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan bump
[ INFO] [1396554687.373924581]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1396554687.994371819]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1396554688.069237432]: Sim period is set to 0.20
[ INFO] [1396554690.131045226]: odom received!
```

**Where does amcl_demo.launch its plugins from?**

(ROS Distro is Hydro and Ubuntu is 13.04).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148301/where-does-amcl_demo.launch-load-its-plugins-from?/) by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually a really good question, and given the state of the documentation not trivial to find out. I haven't used costmaps heavily myself, only `move_base` without changing the default config much, so I had to some digging in the code to see whats going on. The output `Loading from pre-hydro parameter style` gives some hint.

So in the `amcl_demo.launch` file through includes eventually the `move_base` node is started. This node includes two cost maps (local and global), which are run inside the node (not as seperate nodes). This could be the first confusion. The corresponding objects are created [here (move_base.cpp#L111)](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L111) and [here (move_base.cpp#L139)](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L139). You can see that the costmaps are invoked with the names `global_costmap` and `local_costmap`. This is important for specifying the parameters correctly.

In the launch include file where move base is specified, you can see that there are 4 lines to load parameters for the 2 costmaps ([move_base.launch.xml#L11-L14](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/hydro/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml#L11-L14)). Notice the extra `ns="global_costmap"` and `ns="local_costmap"` tags when loading `costmap_common_params.yaml`. The two other parameter files specifying parameters specific to local and global costmap have this namespace inside the `.yaml` file. So now we know where the parameters for the two costmaps are specified. But why is there nothing about `plugins`?

We have to dig further and have a look inside the Costmap2DROS node. During initialization of the costmap, it checks ([costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L107-L110](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L107-L110)) if the parameter `plugins` is set (in the private namespace). If not, it calls function `resetOldParameters`, which sets up the plugin parameters from within the node to mimick some default behaviour.

So in order to change the plugins for example for the local costmap, first check in the `resetOldParameters` code to see how the parameters are set up (or use `rosparam` to inspect the parameters after the node was started). Then modify the yaml file for the local costmap (`local_costmap_params.yaml` in the turtlebot amcl demo) to specify the default plugins to get back to the default behaviour. If that works as expected, you can now add your additional custom plugins to this file.

@David Lu, @tfoote: As maintainers of the the navigation stack / turtlebot_navigation package, it would probably be very helpful if the example launch files in `move_base` and/or `turtlebot_navigation` and/or `costmap_2d` would actually use the post-electric style parameterization of costmaps explicitely listing the layers in the `plugins` parameter. Otherwise there is a discrepancy between the costmap tutorial and the examples.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-07**:
Thanks a lot for the detailed response!

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-07**:
What I don't understand is why I would be making changes to the local costmap with static_map set to false and rolling_window set to true, considering that my aim is to load a (static?) layer with a lethal obstacle one meter ahead of the robot...

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-07**:
Since you want to place something relative to the robot, it for obstacle avoidance, it seems the local costmap is the right choice. I'm not sure how the rolling_window option will be interacting with you plugin. I suggest trying it or checking the source code on more details about rolloing_window.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-07**:
Also, it depends a bit on what exactly you want to achieve with your custom layer. Maybe you can share a bit more on the actual goal of all this.

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-08**:
OK you were right; adding the plugins (the same stuff in the minimal.yaml file here: http://bit.ly/1qggQa7) to the local_costmap_params.yaml file does the trick. My main aim is to do this - http://bit.ly/1swomQj - and load it as a separate layer on my costmap for social navigation of my robot.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-08**:
Good to know :)

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-08**:
So just another follow-up question: when this new layer is loaded, does the robot actually consider the 'fake' obstacle as a 'real' obstacle? I ask because it seems to have no problem 'walking through' it :S

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-08**:
I believe the local costmap is used for the local planner for doing obstacle avoidance. The global path planner is using only the global costmap I believe, so this will not consider your obstacle unless you also add something to the global costmap.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-08**:
So I expect the robot to ignore the additional obstacles when planning a path, but still try to avoid it when trying to follow the path.